# Nightmare Expression Tree with over-constrained class

Tags: c++, expression-trees, friend

I inadvertently let my students overconstrain a shared class used to solve the following problem. I realized it might be a problem denizens of this site might enjoy.

The first team/function, getNodes, takes a string representing a prefix expression using signed integers and the four operations +, -, *, and / and produces the corresponding null terminated linked list of tokens, using the class Node, with tokens linked through the "right" pointer.

The second team/function, getTree, takes a similar string, passes it to getNodes, and relinks the resultant nodes to be an expression tree.

The third team/function, evaluate, takes a similar string, passes it to getTree, and evaluates the resultant expression tree to form an answer.

The over-constrained exptree.h follows. The problem has to be solved by writing just the three functions defined above, no additional functions.

```
#ifndef EXPTREE_H_
#define EXPTREE_H_

using namespace std;

enum Ops{ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV, NUM};

class Node {
   private:
        int num;
        Ops op;
        Node *left, *right;

    public:
        friend Node *getNodes(string d);
        friend Node *getTree(string d);
        friend int evaluate (string);
    };

int evaluate(string d);
Node *getNodes(string d);
Node *getTree(string d);
#endif
```

The only libraries that can be used are these

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "exptree.h"
```

For those of you worried about my students, I will be pointing out today how just a couple of more well placed functions would allow this problem to be easily solved. I know the expression tree can code rational numbers and not just integers. I'll be pointing that out today as well.

Here is the driver program I gave them based on their specs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "exptree.h"
using namespace std;
void test(string s, int target) {
    int result = evaluate(s);
    if (result == target)
        cout << s << " correctly evaluates to " << target << endl;
    else
        cout << s << "(" << result 
             << ") incorrectly evaluates to " << target << endl;
}
int main() {
    test("42", 42);
    test("* - / 4 2 1 42", 42);
    test("* - / -4 +2 -1 2", -2);
    test("* - / -4 +2 -1 2            ", -2);
    test("* 9 6", 54);
    return 0;
}
```

Can you write the three functions in as elegant a fashion as possible to solve this nightmarish problem?

Comment: I solved this same problem (as I bet everyone has) in one of my classes a year or so ago. We solved it by making the evaluate polymorphic. Multiply nodes would multiply their left and right, value nodes would simply return their value, and so forth. Made the program self writing :) I realize this goes against your "Write only three functions" constraint, but it might be something interesting to introduce them to.

Comment: Are the tokens guaranteed to be space delimited like in your examples?

Comment: "The only libraries that can be used are these" `<string>`? Bit hard to define the functions otherwise ;-)

Comment: -1: Does the answer have to compile? The driver program won't. `string` in `exptree.h` is not in the global namespace by the time `exptree.h` is included in the driver program.

Comment: @rob Wow, the only problem is including `<string>` and `using namespace std` or prefixing the `string`s. What's the big deal?

Comment: You are right, string was implied, since it is necessary as a parameter type. You are also right, "using namespace std" is also required. My students opted to avoid needing polymorphism or more than one kind of Node through use of adding "NUM" as part of the enumerated type "Ops"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what its worth, here is the solution I coded up just before I posted the question

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "exptree.h"
using namespace std;

Node *getNodes(string s) {
    const int MAXINT =(int)(((unsigned int)-1) >> 1), MININT = -MAXINT -1;
    Node *list;
    int sign, num;

    s += " ";                                                   // this simplifies a lot of logic, allows trailing white space to always close off an integer
    list = (Node *) (num = sign = 0);
    for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
        char c = s[i];                                          // more efficient and cleaner reference to the current character under scrutiny
        if (isdigit(c)) {
            if (sign == 0) sign = 1;                            // if sign not set, then set it. A blank with a sign==0 now signifies a blank that can be skipped
            num = 10*num + c - '0';
        } else if (((c=='+') || (c=='-')) && isdigit(s[i+1])) { // another advantage of adding blank to string above so don't need a special case
            sign = (c=='+') ? 1 : -1;
        } else if ( !isspace(c) &&  (c != '+')  && (c != '-')  && (c != '*')  && (c != '/')) {
            cout << "unexpected character " << c << endl;
            exit(1);
        } else if  (!isspace(c) || (sign != 0)) {                                                       // have enough info to create next Node
            list->left = (list == 0) ? (list = new Node) : (list->left->right = new Node);              // make sure left pointer of first Node points to last Node
            list->left->right = 0;                                                                      // make sure list is still null terminated
            list->left->op = (c=='+' ? ADD : (c=='-' ? SUB : (c=='*' ? MUL : (c=='/' ? DIV : NUM))));   // choose right enumerated type
            list->left->num = (list->left->op==NUM) ? sign*num : MININT;                                // if interior node mark number for evaluate function
            num = sign = 0;                                                                             // prepare for next Node
        }
    }
    return list;
}

Node *getTree(string s) {
    Node *nodes = getNodes(s), *tree=0, *root, *node;
    vector<Node *> stack;

    if (nodes == 0) return tree;
    root = tree = nodes;
    nodes = nodes->right;
    for (node=nodes; node != 0; node=nodes) {
        nodes = nodes->right;
        if (root->op != NUM) {              // push interior operator Node on stack til time to point to its right tree
            stack.push_back(root);
            root = (root->left = node);     // set interior operator Node's left tree and prepare to process that left tree
        } else {                            
            root->left = root->right = 0;   // got a leaf number Node so finish it off
            if (stack.size() == 0) break;
            root = stack.back();            // now pop operator Node off the stack
            stack.pop_back();
            root = (root->right = node);    // set its left tree and prepare to process that left tree
        }
    }
    if ((stack.size() != 0) || (nodes != 0)) {
        cout << "prefix expression has missing or extra terms" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return tree;
}

int evaluate(string s) {
    // MININT is reserved value signifying operator waiting for a left side value, low inpact since at edge of representable integers
    const int MAXINT =(int)(((unsigned int)-1) >> 1), MININT = -MAXINT -1;
    Node *tree = getTree(s);
    vector<Node *> stack;
    int v = 0;                              // this is value of a leaf node (a number) or the result of evaluating an interior node
    if (tree == 0) return v;
    do {
        v = tree->num;
        if (tree->op != NUM) {
            stack.push_back(tree);
            tree = tree->left;              // prepare to process the left subtree      
        } else while (stack.size() != 0) {  // this while loop zooms us up the right side as far as we can go (till we come up left side or are done)
            delete tree;                    // done with leaf node or an interior node we just finished evaluating
            tree = stack.back();            // get last interior node from stack
            if (tree->num == MININT) {      // means returning up left side of node, so save result for later
                tree->num = v;
                tree = tree->right;         // prepare to evaluate the right subtree
                break;                      // leave the "else while" for the outer "do while" which handles evaluating an expression tree
            } else {                        // coming up right side of an interior node (time to calculate)
                stack.pop_back();           // all done with interior node
                v = tree->op==ADD ? tree->num+v : (tree->op==SUB ? tree->num-v : (tree->op==MUL ? tree->num*v : tree->num/v)) ;
            }
        }
    } while (stack.size() != 0);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: `list = (Node *) (num = sign = 0);` this is most definitly NOT pretty!

Comment: I guess beauty is in the eye of the beholder. It was a compact way of initializing three things to zero. Fitting related code on a screen is also a pretty thing to do.

Comment: Beauty is also in the eye of the compiler ;) .  One-liners < warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The `getNodes` and `getTree` functions would be pretty trivial to write under these constraints, so I just skipped ahead to the interesting part. You would naturally evaluate an expression tree recursively, but that is not an option here because the eval function only takes a string. Sure, you could restringify the remaining tree into a prefix expression and call eval recursively on that, but that would just be stupid.

First, I convert the expression tree into a postfix expression, using an explicit stack as the poor man's recursion. Then I evaluate that with the standard operand stack.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "exptree.h" 

int evaluate(string d){
    Node* tree = getTree(d);
   //convert tree to postfix for simpler evaluation
    vector<Node*> node_stack;
    node_stack.push_back(tree);
    Node postfix_head;
    Node* postfix_tail = &postfix_head;
    while(node_stack.size() > 0){
        Node* place = node_stack.back();
        if(place->left == 0){
             if(place->right == 0){
                 postfix_tail->right = place;
                 node_stack.pop_back();
             } else {
                 node_stack.push_back(place->right);
                 place->right = 0;
             }
        } else {
            node_stack.push_back(place->left);
            place->left = 0;
        }
    }
   //evaluate postfix
    Node* place = postfix_head.right;
    vector<int> stack;
    while(place != 0){
        if(place->op != NUM){
            int operand_a, operand_b;
            operand_b = stack.back();
            stack.pop_back();
            operand_a = stack.back();
            stack.pop_back();
            switch(place->op){
                case ADD:
                    stack.push_back(operand_a + operand_b);
                    break;
                case SUB:
                    stack.push_back(operand_a - operand_b);
                    break;
                case MUL:
                    stack.push_back(operand_a * operand_b);
                    break;
                case DIV:
                    stack.push_back(operand_a / operand_b);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            stack.push_back(place->num);
        }
        place = place->right;
    }
    return stack.back();
}
```

Comment: This is nice start on a solution, very FORTHright. It seg faulted when I ran it on line "operand_b = stack.back();". It looks like your stack went empty. getnodes is easy to write. getTree takes a little finessing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "no additional functions" is a too tough requirement. The easiest way to implement e.g. `getTree` is probably recursive, and it requires defining an additional function.

```
Node* relink(Node* start) // builds a tree; returns the following node
{
    if (start->op == NUM)
    {
        Node* result = start->right;
        start->left = start->right = NULL;
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        start->left = start->right;
        start->right = relink(start->left);
        return relink(start->right);
    }
}

Node* getTree(string d)
{
    Node* head = getNodes(d);
    relink(head);
    return head;
}
```

I could implement recursion by using an explicit stack (implemented by `std::vector`) but that is ugly and obscure (unless you want you students to practice exactly that).

Comment: It is easy to write with the extra two functions that allow recursion. Of course, I don't intend my students to have to do an explicit stack. When I solved it, I was surprised how pretty the solution was. I too expected using an explicit stack would be ugly. I was wrong. I walked my students through my solution today. It actually was pretty useful. I am not so interested in my students practicing; I do want them to solve reasonable problems; this one was not reasonable for them, but I figured stackoverflow folk might enjoy it.